# HTML shuttle launch Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a HTML code with Javascript. For the past two weeks, I've been trying to build a platform using validation. I've coded and checked along the way, but somehow the code is not responding any more and I am confused on what did I wrong.

This is to use validation to ensure I have the information needed to launch the shuttle program. I've used forms and DOM to code, but now I am having trouble with my completed project not populating.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 let form = document.querySelector("form");

 form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  let items = document.getElementById('faultyItems');
  let launchStatus = document.getElementById('launchStatus');
  let fuelStatus = document.getElementById('fuelStatus');
  let cargoStatus = document.getElementById('cargoStatus')
  let ready = true;

  let pilotName = document.querySelector("input[name=pilotName]").value;
  let copilotName = document.querySelector("input[name=copilotName]").value;
  let fuelLevel = document.querySelector("input[name=fuelLevel]").value;
  let cargoMass = document.querySelector("input[name=cargoMass]").value;

  if (pilotName === "" || copilotName === "" || fuelLevel === '' || isNaN(fuelLevel) || cargoMass === '' || isNaN(cargoMass) ) {

   alert("All fields are required!");
   items.style.visibility = 'hidden';

   launchStatus.style.color = 'black';
   launchStatus.innerHTML = 'Awaiting Information Before Launch';

  } else {

   items.style.visibility = 'visible';

   document.getElementById('pilotStatus').innerHTML = `Pilot ${ pilotName + ' ' }Ready`
   document.getElementById('copilotStatus').innerHTML = `Co-pilot ${ copilotName + ' ' }Ready`

   if (fuelLevel < 10000) {
    ready = false;
    fuelStatus.innerHTML = 'Not enough fuel for launch';
   } else {
    fuelStatus.innerHTML = 'Fuel level high enough for launch';
   }

   if (cargoMass > 10000) {
    ready = false;
    cargoStatus.innerHTML = 'Too much mass for the shuttle to take off';
   } else {
    cargoStatus.innerHTML = 'Cargo mass low enough for launch';
   }

   if (ready) {
    launchStatus.style.color = 'green';
    launchStatus.innerHTML = 'Shuttle is ready for launch';
    retrieveData();
   } else {
    items.style.visibility = 'visible';
    launchStatus.style.color = 'red';
    launchStatus.innerHTML = 'Shuttle not ready for launch';
   }

  }

 });
});


function retrieveData() {

 fetch('https://handlers.education.launchcode.org/static/planets.json').then( function (response) {
  response.json().then(function (data) {
   let targets = document.getElementById('missionTarget');
   let random = Math.round(Math.random() * data.length);
   let target = data[random];

   targets.innerHTML =
    `<h2>Mission Destination</h2>
    <ol>
       <li>Name: ${target.name}</li>
       <li>Diameter: ${target.diameter}</li>
       <li>Star: ${target.stat}</li>
       <li>Distance from Earth: ${target.distance}</li>
       <li>Number of Moons: ${target.moons}</li>
    </ol>
    <img src="${target.image}">`


  });
 })

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Launch Checklist</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles.css" />
        <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Launch Checklist Form</h1>
        <div id="missionTarget">
            <!-- Fetch some planetary data -->
           
        </div>
        <div id="launchForm">
            <form>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Pilot Name <input type="text" name="pilotName" id="pilotName"/></label>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Co-pilot Name <input type="text" name="copilotName"/></label>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Fuel Level (gal) <input type="text" name="fuelLevel"/></label>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Cargo Weight (lbs) <input type="text" name="cargoWeight"/></label>
                </div>
                <button id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="launchStatusCheck">
            <h2 id="launchStatus">Awaiting Information Before Launch</h2>
            <div  id="faultyItems">
                <ol>
                    <li id="pilotStatus">Pilot Ready</li>
                    <li id="copilotStatus">Co-pilot Ready</li>
                    <li id="fuelStatus">Fuel level high enough for launch</li>
                    <li id="cargoStatus">Cargo weight low enough for launch</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to populate an alert if form not completed or invalid. I also expect to the shuttle requirements to update when the shuttle is ready or not ready.

If someone can explain what I am doing wrong would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
        let cargoMass = document.querySelector("input[name=cargoMass]").value;
```

With

```
        let cargoMass = document.querySelector("input[name=cargoWeight]").value;
```

I’m assuming you mixed up mass and weight.

For the future, see console messages.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I think I just needed a fresh pair of eyes to get the outcome.